# SSIS package failing when trying to deploy : Assembly Error

Tags: ssis

I had a 2016 sql server and we needed to migrate to 2019 but in doing so we wanted to keep the same IP & hostname as it was the easier route for other apps that connect to this server to still be able to function properly instead of making those changes in each web application. I stood up a new sql server and migrated all the dbs, logins, jobs, etc.. to the new 2019 server from 2016. So, now the old 2016 server became the new 2019 server with the old IP & Hostname.

However, I have one SSIS job that is failing after the migration: it is all setup in VisualStudio then deployed in SSISDB. I even backed up restored the SSISDB from the old server.

I am getting this error when trying to re-deploy the ssis project:

**
An error occurred in the Microsoft .NET Framework while trying to load assembly id 65536. The server may be running out of resources, or the assembly may not be trusted. Run the query again, or check documentation to see how to solve the assembly trust issues. For more information about this error:
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.integrationservices.server, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. An error relating to security occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013150A)
System.IO.FileLoadException:
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10314)

For help, click: https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-10314-database-engine-error **

Please help as I am totally lost on this.

Comment: try to build a simple SSIS project and deploy and see it works. NOte to use the latest ssis version which is suitable for 2019.